# Showing that any field extension of a finite field is simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> We know that the multiplicative subgroup $F^\times$ of a finite field $F$ is cyclic. Use this to show that any field extension of a finite field is simple.

Any clues?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Bernard points out, your statement is false the way you've written it. For example, the fields $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ and $\mathbb{F}_p(x,y)$ are not simple extensions of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

However, what you probably meant to write is that if $F$ is a finite field, then any field extension $K/F$ **of finite degree** is simple. **This is true**. Since the degree $[K:F]$ being finite implies that $K$ is itself a finite field, we know that $K^\times$ is cyclic. Let $u$ be a generator of $K^\times$. Then $K=F(u)$ because $F(u)$ has at least $|K|-1$ elements, since the multiplicative order of $u$ is $|K^\times|$. But since $F(u)$ is an $F$-vector space, it must have at least $|K|$ elements, and since $F(u)$ is a subfield of $K$, it must be equal to $K$. Thus the extension $K/F$ is simple.

Comment: Yes,now everything has sense. The task were exactly how I wrote it. Thank's a lot!

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes. Maybe I made a fool, when I was copying from board.

Comment: @MrFrodo Ah, OK. So then probably you just missed the word "finite" (field extension), and Zev has the right interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

It is false: if it were, any algebraic extension of a finite field $F$ would be a finite extension of $F$, hence its algebraic closure would be a finite field. It's easy to show an algebraically closed field can't be finite.

Comment: @Zev Cholones: I first thought like you, but  finally thought he probably already had the case of finite extensions of finite fields as an example of simple extensions.

Comment: Ah, I see. At any rate, I certainly agree that things are not clear on the OP's end.